# i can't get data of any components while using contextApi

Tags: reactjs, react-context

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

const News = ()=> {

  let API = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=html";

  const fetchApiData = async (url) => {
    try {
      const res  = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApiData(API)
  })

  return (
    <div>news</div>
  )
}

export default News

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt6Ic.png)
[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grnZC.png)
[ContextApi.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KIeb.png)
[localhost][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcHqU.png
```

before adding provider tag in index.js all the components data were showing on localhost (like "hello" "news" etc... which is writen in jsx) but when i add AppProvider in index.js these all jsx were vanished and contextApi's data ("...state" which is string) also don't showing

Comment: Please, fix the format of the image sources.

Comment: Also, instead of screenshots of your code, please embed any relevant code as actual formatted text in your question. You can refer to [this doc for question asking tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your ContextApi is wrong, try like this and then you can use ContextApi to save via

`const { setData } = useContext(ContextApi)`;

```
import * as React from "react";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState("...state");
  const value = { data, setData };
  return <AppContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

Comment: still having same problem

Comment: What exactly problem? You can look at code like yours but with some setup news https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-microservice-8m787k?file=/src/App.js